# PowerMockito verifyNew withArguments of an object and an array of objects

Tags: java, junit, junit4, powermockito

i am trying to test that a method creates an object. i have it almost working using PowerMockito.verifyNew().withArguments() however, the Arguments that are passed to the constructor are an object and an ArrayList of objects. the output of the test is:
Actual

```
invocationSubstitute.performSubstitutionLogic(
1,
6,
11,
13,
[au.edu.sccs.csp3105.NBookingPlanner.Person@2449cff7],
au.edu.sccs.csp3105.NBookingPlanner.Room@62da83ed,
"description"
);
```

Expected

```
invocationSubstitute.performSubstitutionLogic(
1,
6,
11,
13,
[au.edu.sccs.csp3105.NBookingPlanner.Person@40bffbca],
au.edu.sccs.csp3105.NBookingPlanner.Room@42a9a63e,
"description"
);
```

i can see that the problem is the objects are the same type but not the same object, is there a way of saying the Expected object is of the correct type?

test:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Planner.class, Meeting.class})

public class MonthInput {

Planner planner;

@Rule
    public final TextFromStandardInputStream systemInMock = emptyStandardInputStream();
@Rule
    public final ExpectedSystemExit exit = ExpectedSystemExit.none();

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Before
public void setup() throws Exception {
    Meeting meetingMock = Mockito.mock(Meeting.class);
    PowerMockito.whenNew(Meeting.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(meetingMock);     
}

@Test
public void MonthInputofless5() throws Exception {
    // make spy
    planner = Mockito.spy(Planner.class);

    //override main menu with do nothing
    Mockito.doNothing().when(planner).mainMenu();

    //provide inputs
    systemInMock.provideLines("1","6","11","13","ML13.218","Mark Colin","done","description");

    //set expected outputs
    ArrayList<Person> attendees = new ArrayList<Person>();
    attendees.add(new Person("Mark Colin"));
    Room where = new Room("ML13.218");

    //call the method
    planner.scheduleMeeting();

    //set passing terms     
    PowerMockito.verifyNew(Meeting.class).withArguments(1,6,11,13,attendees,where,"description");

}
```

Comment: Wrong approach: if you want that a certain object is created, then enable yourself to **access** that object. Then just assertThat() that object matches your expectations. Seriously: your tests should be straight forward. When they are not, don't start using "bizarre" features, instead improve your design so that it becomes easier to test.

Comment: how would i give myself access to an object like that? would that not brake the encapsulation of the object?

Comment: You could introduce a package protected getter method (marked as unit test only). And then you implement an appropriate equals method. And note checking the parameters coming in via the constructor isn't the same as checking the real object for expected content.

Comment: Thank you for your help, i still don't see how adding a greeter to the meeting class wont brake encapsulation and it would be a lot of work for all the classes that need to be tested. The test is cheeking that the method calls the constructor with the expected arguments, i am not trying to test if the created class is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Fix your code

A verify simple fix on your classes: implement `hashCode` and `equals` on `Person` and `Room` so Powermock verification can actually compare two objects for equality and not just rely on the object reference.

#### Fix your tests

If you don't want to fix your code, but the test, you could either use a Mockito matcher (i.e. `org.mockito.Matchers.eq` or `org.mockito.Matchers.any`). But please note, that `eq` relies on `equals` and won't work unless you implement it (see above). But `any` would match any object of that type (surprise!)

```
PowerMockito.verifyNew(Meeting.class)
            .withArguments(eq(1),eq(6),eq(11),eq(13), 
                          any(List.class),
                          any(Room.class),
                          eq("description"));
```

If the actual value matters, you could use an ArgumentCapture instead of a matcher and check the captured value.

*Theoretically*, it should look like this:

```
final ArgumentCaptor<Person> personCaptor = forClass(Person.class);
final ArgumentCaptor<Room> roomCaptor = forClass(Room.class);
 PowerMockito.verifyNew(Planner.class)
             .withArguments(eq(1),eq(6),eq(11),eq(13), 
                  personCaptor.capture(), 
                  roomCaptor.capture(), 
                  eq("description"));

    final Person passedParam = personCaptor.getValue();
    //do your comparison here
```

But I didn't get the capture example running, so maybe that's only possible with plain Mockito.

#### Just don't!

All that said, you should verify your overall approach. Using Whitebox-Testing may create very brittle tests and won't help much in refactoring and may further foster bad class design.

The imprudent use of Powermockito is an *anti-pattern*. It's a very mighty tool for testing the untestable, i.e. badly designed legacy code from the dark ages of the internet where the homepages were handcrafted HTMLs and full of wobbly GIFs. 
Don't use it for new, greenfield projects. Just don't.

Instead try focusing on the *observable* result of any action. Invoking the `scheduleMeeting()` method may produce any result that is more easy to check - it's the result that matters, not the way to get they. Trust me, not a single user gets happier when a constructor was called.

Results could be

- an instance of a meeting (as return value, that would be best in your example)
- a state change in the planner (any getters?)
- a state change in a downstream service / db
- a written file
- an output written to System.out

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, i am not testing legacy code exactly but the implementation is not mine to modify. i am only writing the tests for the code, that was written to be a challenge to test. e.g not 1 return at all. as for your provided solution when i pass attendees or where to any() i get "any(Class<T>) in the type ArgumentMatchers is not applicable for the arguments (Room)" its not accepting the object and only wants Room.class. using any() on its own is working. The eq(int) was what i needed so thanks again for the help

Comment: you're right, it's a typo in my example, `any()` means "any object", while `any(Room.class)` means "any instance of Room" ...