# Mock new PrintWriter(String fileName) using Mockito

Tags: junit, mockito, junit5

I have a code

```
                csvWriter.writeCsv(new PrintWriter(csvPath), someList);
```

Is it possible to test string ".\xyz.csv" and TestUtil.getSomeList() exactly.

Below mockito code is giving me error "Argument(s) are different! Wanted" complaining about different PrintWriter objects.

```
verify(csvWriter, times(1)).writeCsv(new PrintWriter(".\\xyz.csv"), TestUtil.getSomeList());
```

It works if I change this to

```
verify(csvWriter, times(2)).writeCsv(any(PrintWriter.class), any(List.class));
```

But I would like to verify that ".\xyz.csv" and TestUtil.getSomeList() are matched exactly. Is it possible?

Comment: Thanks @Anatolli Chub. Works like charm for second argument. I used listCaptor.getAllValues() to get list of list. Is it possible to also check ".\\xyz.csv" somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ArgumentCaptor` to get the parameters you put to the `writeCsv` method:

```
ArgumentCaptor<PrintWriter> writerCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(PrintWriter.class);
ArgumentCaptor<> listCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(List.class);
verify(csvWriter, times(2)).writeCsv(writerCaptor.capture, listCaptor.capture());

//Then you can check captured parameters:
List<...> actualList = listCaptor.getValue();

assertEquals(expectedList, actualList);
```

Sample : https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-argumentcaptor

Comment: Thanks @Anatolli Chub. Works like charm for second argument. I used listCaptor.getAllValues() to get list of list. Is it possible to also check ".\\xyz.csv" somehow?

Comment: I'm not sure that it's a good aproach but you can try to verfiy concstructor(PrintWriter) call with arguments. PowerMockito library allows it, as I know.  Check this answer, maybe it will be useful:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50349699/16210149

Comment: @Anatolli Chub. Thanks. I guess I will leave it at that as not a good idea.